# Forcing WCF proxy to generate an alias prefix

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

To comply with a clients schema, I've been attempting to generate a WCF client proxy capable of serializing down to a structure with a root node that looks like the following:

```
<quote:request
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:quote="https://example.com/services/schema/1.2/car_quote">
```

After some reading, I've had luck in updating the proxy to include the required 'quote' namespace through the use of XmlNameSpaceDeclarations and XmlSerializerNamespaces

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
public partial class request
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations()]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlsn
    {
        get
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xsn.Add("quote", "https://example.com/services/schema/1.2/car_quote");
            return xsn;
        }
        set
        {
            //Just provide an empty setter. 
        }
    }
    ...
```

which delivers:

```
<request
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:quote="https://example.com/services/schema/1.2/car_quote">
```

however I'm stumped as to how to generate the quote:request element.

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5

Comment: Your client's schema should not actually have cared whether the prefix was "quote" or "etouq", or anything in between. It's the namespace that matters, not the prefix, which is just an alias for the namespace. Any code that actually cares which prefix is used should be fixed immediately or at least publicly ridiculed for violating basic XML standards.

Comment: Another aside: your problem wasn't that you didn't generate the prefix: your problem was that your element wasn't generated in the correct namespace. As an experiment, you should try fixing the namespace problem, then removing the `[XmlNamespaceDeclarations]` attribute and see if the client's code still works.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really reproduce your situation without some WSDL to generate a proxy from, but the serialization bit works for me if I add an `XmlRoot` attribute.

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[XmlRoot(Namespace="https://example.com/services/schema/1.2/car_quote")]
public partial class request
{
    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations()]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlsn
    {
        get 
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            xsn.Add("quote", "https://example.com/services/schema/1.2/car_quote");
            return xsn;
        }
        set { }
    } 
}
```