# WCF SOAP reply to ASMX SOAP reply format

Tags: wcf, soap

I have one third party SOAP client that is capable of communicating with old ASMX webservices.

The problem is with a WCF services.

My WCF service receives messages from this client without problems, but the client does not like my WCF responses.

My test WCF service sends out the following response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <testResponse xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org">
   <testResult>randomStringData</testResult>
  </testResponse>
 </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

But the old SOAP Client expects this kind of response(ASMX service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <soap:Body>
  <testResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <testResult>randomStringData</testResult>
  </testResponse>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have no control over the client.
Is there a way i could configure my WCF to send out exactly the same message as my ASMX service does?

My WCF Service is using the following binding:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="soap11">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8"></textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport></httpTransport>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Comment: If the only difference between those two responses is "s:" as opposed to "soap:", then the two are identical as far as XML is concerned. Even to a legacy ASMX service or client, the two will be identical. Namespace prefixes ("s:") are just aliases for the actual namespace, and the namespaces are the same.

Comment: I have a feeling that the old SOAP client has hard coded xml parsing and is searching for a string "<soap:". Is there a easy way to change the prefix?

Comment: I think John is right about `s:`  being same as `soap:` anyway you can give a try to curl to actually send raw xml, so you can configure soap call with soap: as namespace

Comment: Can you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254544/how-do-i-specify-xml-serialization-attributes-to-support-namespace-prefixes-duri ? or another http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020459/forcing-wcf-proxy-to-generate-an-alias-prefix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve the prefix problem with custom message inspector and with BeforeSendReply method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.beforesendreply.aspx

P.S Another great method is AfterReceiveRequest for all kind of message tweaking magic!

Comment: If changing the prefix actually worked, then you should file a bug report with the owner of that service. The actual prefix is completely meaningless. Or rather, it _should_ be completely meaningless. Help your partner by making sure they know about this.

Comment: Already done :) And the answer was as expected... Use standard! Our standard! lol.